# Prove that $A$ is closed set

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $f_n$ as:

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1-\frac{1}{n}, & \text{ if } \frac1n\le x \le 1\\0, & \text{ if  } x=0\end{cases}$$

and linear on the rest (but so that the function is continuous, basically connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $\left(\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)$ on the graph of function $f_n$).

Now when considering the set $A=\{f_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Why $A$ is a closed set in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: Closed set in what space?

Comment: What is the domain of $f_n$? What do you mean by $A$ being "a closed set in $R$"? The elements of $A$ are not even elements of $\mathbb R$ -- is the $R$ you speak about something different from the set of real numbers?

Comment: In the $R$ space

Comment: @GilBenDavid: Please explain what you mean by "the $R$ space", rather than just repeating that undefined letter.

Comment: $A$ is a set of *functions*. "$A$ closed in $\Bbb R$" is nonsensical.

Comment: sorry, i've confused with other question. i meant C[0,1] space

Comment: Getting better -- $C[0,1]$ is at least something that $A$ is a subset of -- but $C[0,1]$ is _not a topological space_ (until you specify a particular topology to use for it), and therefore speaking about a subset of it being closed is _still_ nonsense.

Comment: So do you equip the $\mathcal C[0,1]$ with the sup norm? Namely, $|f|:=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$?

Comment: ok, i'll explain. the base question was to find in $C[0,1]$ closed and bounded set $A$ such that there are no $f,g \in A$ that imply $\operatorname{diam}(A)=d(f,g)$, where $\operatorname{diam}(A) = \sup\{d(f,g)\mid f,g \in A\}$.

Comment: one of the answer was to define the set above

Comment: Well, what's your metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ then?

Comment: $d(f,g)=max\|f(t)-g(t)\| , t \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Key observation:** If $j\ge 2k$ then $d(f_j,f_k)\ge \frac12$.

Given this observation we can show directly that $A$ is closed. Assume that $(a_i)_i$ is a sequence of elements of $a$ that converge to some $L\in C[0,1]$; we then need to show that $L\in A$.

Apply the definition of convergence with $\varepsilon=\frac14$; this gives an $N$ such that $d(a_n,L)<\frac14$ for all $n\ge N$. Suppose that $a_n=f_k$.

Now suppose there an $m>N$ such that $a_m$ is $f_j$ for some $j\ge 2k$. Then, by the key observation above we have $d(a_n,a_m)\ge\frac12$, but this contradicts the triangle inequality because $d(a_n,L)$ and $d(L,a_m)$ are both less than $\frac14$. So such an $m$ cannot exist.

This means that for all $m>N$, $a_m$ must be $f_j$ for some $j<2k$. In other words there are only finitely many different elements among the $a_i$s. And it holds generally in a metric space that a sequence with only finitely many different elements must converge to one of those elements, or not at all. So $L$ must be one of the elements in the sequence, and therefore in $A$.

Comment: can you explain the key observation?

Comment: @GilBenDavid  you might want to draw a few graphs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the sup norm in $\mathcal C[0,1]$, it is easy to see that $A$ has *no* limit point in the space and is thus closed.

Suppose on the contrary that $A$ should have a limit point say $f$ in $\mathcal C[0,1]$, then by definition you can pick a sequence (comprising distinct points) $\{f_{n_k}\},k=1,2,\cdots$ in $\mathcal C[0,1]$ such that $f_{n_k}\to f$ by the sup norm as $k\to\infty$. In other words, $f_{n_k}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. But this is impossible, since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, and $f_{n_k}$ apparently convergens pointwisely to a discontinuous function on $[0,1]$.

To elaborate, suppose $f\in\mathcal C[0,1]$, pick $t\in(0,1]$, then $|f_{n_k}(t)-f(t)|\le d(f_{n_k},f)$. For any $\epsilon>0$, choose $k$ so large so that: 1). $d(f_{n_k},f)<\epsilon$; 2). $t>\frac1k\ge\frac1{n_k}$; 3). $\frac1{n_k}\le\frac1k<\epsilon$, then 
$$|f(t)-1|\le|f_{n_k}(t)-1|+|f_{n_k}(t)-f(t)|<\frac1{n_k}+d(f_{n_k},f)<2\epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we see that $f(t)=1$, but it is also apparent that $f(0)=0$, contradicting the continuity.